# Targeting a <small> within a <hX>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a kind of interesting item I need to target in CSS: it's a `<small>` inside of a `<h[1-6]>` which is inside of a `<div>` with the classes `alert-message` and `block-message`.

It basically looks like this:

```
<div class="alert-message block-message">
    <h3>
        Hello World
        <small>And Hello Universe, too!</small>
    </h3>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
div.alert-message.block-message h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 small
```

and

```
div.alert-message.block-message h1 small, h2 small, h3 small, h4 small, h5 small, h6 small
```

but neither work, apparently. I simply need to change the font color of these specific `<small>` blocks. What's wrong with my approaches above in "finding" the elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target these specifically, your selector will have to be like this:

```
div.alert-message.block-message h1 small,
div.alert-message.block-message h2 small,
div.alert-message.block-message h3 small,
div.alert-message.block-message h4 small,
div.alert-message.block-message h5 small,
div.alert-message.block-message h6 small {

}
```

I always wished there was a generic selector for `h1-h6`, but unfortunately we need to target them all separately.

> What's wrong with my approaches above in "finding" the elements?

Remember that commas `,` separate selectors, so:

```
div.alert-message.block-message h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 small {}
```

Is the same as:

```
div.alert-message.block-message h1 {/* styles */}
h2 {/* styles */}
h3 {/* styles */}
h4 {/* styles */}
h5 {/* styles */}
h6 small {/* styles */}
```

> I wonder if there's a [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) shortcut?

There's no shortcut for headings I know of, but it looks like you could use nested selectors like this:

```
div.alert-message.block-message {
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        small {/* your CSS */}
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bummer that it has to be this verbose, but thanks for the answer! I wonder if there's a Less shortcut...

Comment: Well, you could always add a class to the headings and then use simply: `.message-heading small {}`

Comment: True, but that would be _so_ much less hacker :)

Answer (score 1):

comma separates whole selectors, not parts of selectors as you seem to be expecting.

`div.alert-message h1,h2` means select `div.alert-message h1` and select `h2` (all of them)

you need to write

```
div.alert-message.block-message h1 small, div.alert-message.block-message h2 small, div.alert-message.block-message h3 small, div.alert-message.block-message h4 small, div.alert-message.block-message h5 small, div.alert-message.block-message h6 small
```

Answer (score 0):

Target each declaration in description one by one.